# Passing Client-Side user information into Server-Side TFS Plugin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, plugins, tfs

I am working on creating a TFS Server-Side plugin for code review policies. The issue I am facing is trying to get the workspace of where the checkin is coming from. Ultimately it is to get the local filepath on the users machine of each of the pending changes to confirm the files last modified date/time.

Currently I am using the

```
string machineName = Environment.MachineName;
string currentUserName = Environment.UserName;
var versioncontrols = tfsTeamProjectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
var workspace = versioncontrols.GetWorkspace(machineName, currentUserName);
```

I use these values to try to get the workspace of where the pending changes are but these just return the computer and user that is hosting the instance of TFS. Not the user or computername of the client side where the check in is actually happening.

if anyone could help find out how to get the client side MachineName and Username that would be a great help...

Or even better if someone could assist in getting the local filepaths on the developers machine from the pending changes, that would solve my end goal issue.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can have a look [here](http://www.almguide.com/2011/12/tfs-server-side-event-handlers/), then I believe you just need to inspect dll to verify workspaces.